# How do I add a compile path to lessc?

Tags: path, less, django-compressor

From less docs [here](http://lesscss.org/usage/index.html#using-less-environments), I would assume that if I want to add a path for lessc to check on imports during compilation, it should take the following format:

```
lessc --include-path=PATH1;PATH2
```

For example, I might use:

```
lessc --include-path=/home/myhome/myproject/less/
```

Then if there are an imports in the less files, I ought to be able to expect less to check this path for those files.  At present though, every attempt I have made to add a path has resulted in the following error: `lessc: no input files`.  No idea why this would be the case, as there are definitely less files in this directory.

Any ideas as to why this is not working?

As a secondary question, how does one inspect the lessc path and change the order in which various paths are tried?

Comment: The error says it all: you did not specify any files to compile. The [`--include-paths`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-include-paths) sets the directories the compiler will look in when searching for [*imports*](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature), the option does not set a directory to compile all Less files in - for that kind of task consider using some higher level build tools/enviroments like `grunt`/`gulp`.

Comment: So figure out the first part, thanks to your comment.  But what about the second question?  It seems when using --include-paths that it wants to look in the specified path second, but I want to make this the first option.  How do you address priority with this option?

Comment: For the second question, no, you can't override current file dir with this option. I.e. for `@import "some.less";` it will always first look in the dir of the file the import is in and only then search within `--include-paths`. So depending on the particular use-case you need some other approach.